# Equation for "tangential stresses across boundary"

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity

I am having trouble deciphering this sentence from Batchelor's An Introduction to Fluid Dynamics. It is at the end of the second paragraph of section 4.2 on Steady Unidirectional Flows.

> Such a motion in the cross sectional plane can survive the viscous dissipation of energy only if there is a continual supply of energy to the fluid by tangential stresses exerted at a portion of the boundary in tangential motion, that is, as may readily be shown, only if $$ \mu \int n_2(ve_{22} + w e_{23}) + n_3(ve_{23} + w e_{33}) > 0 $$

Now I do understand basically what he is saying. He is talking about when unidirectional flows come up, and making the argument that in cylinders without tangential stresses they come up often as there is no energy input to make up for the loss of heat due to viscosity.

**What I don't understand is how he came up with the equation.**

Comment: Your formula has no infinitesimal.

Comment: @Gert - It's an integral over the surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expression for the power supplied by external tractions on the boundary, and noting that only the deviatoric part of the stress is considered due to the fact that only the deviatoric part of the stress causes dissipation.

In general the traction on the boundary is related to the stress as, $t_i = \sigma_{ij} n_j$.

The $y$-component of this traction is $t_y = \mu e_{22} n_2 + \mu e_{23} n_3$ and $t_z = \mu e_{32} n_2 + \mu e_{33} n_3$. The power per unit surface area that must be supplied is then just $t_y v + t_z w$ (i.e. traction dotted with velocity).